# Handling quotes in a TSQL String

Tags: python

I have a python function that builds a TSQL String that inserts a record in a table. I have a problem in the case where one of the values contains a single quote. This is part of ETL where we are reading from an Excel file or a database.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pyodbc
import sys

server_name = 'Server1'
db_name = 'Database1'
sqlConnection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server_name + ';DATABASE=' + db_name + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')


# I have another function that reads Firstname, Lastname, Phone_Number, Address from a spreadsheet into a list named spreadsheet_data.


def InsertEmployee(spreadsheet_data, sqlConnection):
    FirstName = spreadsheet_data[0]
    LastName = spreadsheet_data[1]
Phone_Number= spreadsheet_data[2]
Address = spreadsheet_data[3]

queryEmployeeRecordInserted = """INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.Employee_Info (FirstName, LastName, Phone_Number, Address)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?) """

query = queryEmployeeRecordInserted
cursor = sqlConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, valuesEmployeeRecord)
cursor.close()
sqlConnection.commit()
```

============================================================

If I use this function and the last name has a quote in it (eg: O'Neill) the code fails and I get the error:
(102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string...

How should I handle the code to accommodate quotes (') in the values?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Tried this yesterday but for some reason it did not work. I replaced the quote (') with 2 of them ('') in the variable. It may be quicker to do that before in the entire dataframe but for now it works.

```
    def InsertEmployee(spreadsheet_data, sqlConnection):
        FirstName = spreadsheet_data[0]
        LastName = str(spreadsheet_data[1]).replace("'", "''")
        Phone_Number= spreadsheet_data[2]
        Address = spreadsheet_data[3]
```